# Likelihood function - Sum over $b$ for $P(a\mid b) = P(a)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a conditional probability function $P(y\mid x)$, we know that

$\sum_y P(y\mid x)=1$

When regarding $P(y\mid x)$ as a function of $x$, it is refered to as likelihood function (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Properties)). I've been thinking of what happens when one sums over x and thought that intuitively, we would get back the unconditional probability function $P(y)$. In other words:

$$\sum_x P(y\mid x) = P(y)$$

I've been trying to show this formally, and got the following results:

$$P(y\mid x) = \frac{P(x\mid y)P(y)}{P(x)} \Longrightarrow \sum_xP(y\mid x) = \sum_x \frac{P(x\mid y)P(y)}{P(x)}=P(y)\sum_x\frac{P(x\mid y)}{P(x)}$$

This is where I got stuck and have been told by a person I trust that my intuition is wrong.

My question is, why is this wrong? And are there cases where my intuition is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an extreme situation - what if we look at $P(y \mid y)$? $P(y \mid y) = 1$, no matter what $y$ is. But if $y$ is one of the candidate $x$, then $\sum_xP(y \mid x)$ includes $P(y \mid y)$ as a summand, so it's at least $1$, even if $P(y)$ is only (for example) $0.1$!

The problem is that $P(y \mid x)$ can be very large when $P(x)$ is small, even if $P(y)$ is also small. By contrast, in $\sum_yP(y\mid x)$, $P(x)$ is fixed and so doesn't get this opportunity to "mess up" the scales.

Answer (score 1):

By  law of total probability $$P(y)= \sum_x P(y|x) \color{blue}{P(x)}$$

You have forgotten to consider the likelihood of each $x$ happening.